# How to minimize total size of static data?

Tags: optimization, static-analysis

I am implementing a WASM backend and I hope to optimize the size.

I have collected a series of static data. After erasing the type, it can be simply
considered as `list<u8>`.

However, these data may be repeated or partially covered. I hope to find a way to arrange them, so that the overall size will reduce.

In other words, such a transformation:

`list<list<u8>> -> (data: list<u8>, span: list<(start: u32, length: u32)>)`

But I don't know how to achieve this efficiently. And is there a special name for this kind of optimization?

Comment: It is not clear to me that this is really a question about programming languages, at least without adding more details. As asked, it seems like you are just asking about lossless data compression, which is a rather vast field of its own. Can you clarify what sorts of things you have in mind?

Comment: Assuming I understand correctly, you want to produce a shortest string (of bytes) which contains all of the desired substrings. This is a variant of the travelling saleman problem on a directed graph, where edges have lower weights when the overlap between the two strings is greater. I agree with Alexis; this problem isn't really specific to PLs, it's the kind of thing I'd expect to see in an algorithms textbook. Chances are, for a compiler the possible space savings are small, and for performance it's probably more important to have word-aligned pointers.

Comment: [Related question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285434/efficient-algorithm-for-string-concatenation-with-overlap)

Comment: I think it is impossible to provide an adequate answer without knowing anything about the source language or how much you can influence its semantics or that of core types.

Answer (score 3):

## Compression algorithms

Data compression is about finding repeated data of arbitrary size inside bigger sequential data.

You may not store the data in compressed form, but the *dictionary-building* stage of most compression algorithms are well-studied part of computer sciences.

I suggest starting with classical compression formats like [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch) and [BWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burrows%E2%80%93Wheeler_transform).

The BWT in particular can be extremely efficient in finding *all* substrings in a string, as its algorithm "generates" all rotations of input string and compares all rotations: any two or more rotations that compare equals more than one "letter" is repetition *or* a substring.